# QT Deployment on windows

Tags: windows, qt

**Current Environment:**

Build information : Qt Creator 2.7.0 Based on Qt 5.0.2 (32 bit) with both MinGW as the compiler. XP PRo Box

**Original Environment:**

Original Source was made on qt creator 2.6.2 qt 5.0.1 (32 bit) MinGw on a mac with windows seven.

**Information on What I am Trying to do:**

This Project is being used with a  application called Metatrader 4 and is used to enhance the GUI of Metrader. With in Metatrader I can launch the qt app with shell execute A... some times it works some times it does not.  So I have converted the QT project to a DLL.

**Information on Problem:**

It executes, complies and runs fine on the Boxes with QT deployed and installed. On any other Boxes I get a Error 126.

What I have tried: **

Dependency walker gives me this error API-MS-WIN-CORE-HANDLE-L1-1-0.DLL . 
This current box I am working on has XPRO.

**The Question I would like to ask?**

Why the error 126 when the exe works perfect? any thoughts?

Comment: please care to write normal sentences.

Comment: I retyped Post . I hope it is clear now

Comment: `It executes, complies and runs fine on the Boxes with QT deployed and installed`. You always need Qt... Qt is dynamically linked so the exact version used for building should be on every single other machines (event if your Qt project is a dll itself).

Comment: When complied as a EXE. I just need the dependancies and it runs fine. So you are stating that Complied as a DLL it must have qt Environment install?

Comment: your issue is that "On any other Boxes I get a Error 126.". What is different between the boxes which work and the ones which don't??

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know what `error 126` is. According to MSDN it's `ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND`, so you work from there, most likely it's the `exe` cannot find one of the libraries it's compiled against either due to the path it's looking at being incorrect or similar. Make sure when your `exe` is deployed onto another machine you're also deploying the necessary Qt libraries and deploying them into a place that the exe knows to look in.

Comment: Thanks. The EXE is the working on all machines . The DLL is not. But I am working back trying to find what is missing. Using Dependency walker